# BLE File Transfer from a Device to a Smartphone

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

There is a device and a smartphone with the following requirements:

- User taps the device, says something and their speech is transferred to the smartphone
- The smartphone receives speeches and some other device status information
- Smartphone is iOS device at the beginning (Android and WP devices are considered later)

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to go using Bluetooth to archive that:

1. Standard BT profiles: HFP & HID. iOS SDK doesn't allow direct communication with devices via these profiles. So it's seemed to me very awkward to go this way.
2. BT Low Energy. Is it possible to sent files using BLE? I'm thinking about 50-100K file sizes. If it is, how slow it can be?
3. MFI. This is the last resort. If I go this way, would I have problems with Android and WP smartphones?

**Update**: My original plan was to go with HID (to make app know that device is initiating streaming + other status info) + HFP (to stream). But my concerns were:

1.1. can the app handle HID messages (keypress,for example) while is in background

1.2. can these two profiles work together?

1.3. what pitfalls if another headset is connected (as I understood the latest connected will be streaming)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Will try and go through these one by one:

1. Standard BT:
   Apple: Apple will allow you to use the standard Audio protocols for free. So you could use A2DP to stream Audio, but that is about it. If you want to use SDP to transfer data you will need to get the authentication chip in your device.
   Android: All the protocols are free to access.
2. BLE:
   Apple: BLE is free to use, but I am not sure how Apple will react to you trying to send large amounts of data over the protocol. BLE is very fast for small data (20 bytes) but slows down as you go bigger. A lot is going to depend on your accessory, but I believe Apple has a cap on how fast you can transmit. I have seen speeds of around 5KB/s.
   Android: Same thing applies to Android, but you can go faster if your device supports it, I have seen speeds up to 10KB/s.
3. MFI:
   Apple: Supported by Apple
   Android: The keys that Apple used for Airplay were reverse engineered a while ago, and you might be able to use them but its a gamble. There might be better libraries out there I am not aware of.

When it comes to Windows Phone, I don't know much accept that they did announce something about a BLE api at the BUILD conference that happened a couple of days ago.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I'll add that you can't transfer long file with BLE, Apple should accept, since a few developers do that to update their firmware of their BLE devices.

Comment: @Zomb Thanks for the quick response! But I still need clarifications, sorry :) It looks like the best way to go is Standard BT profiles. Does Apple support A2DP in a way, that a device streams audio to a phone? How can SDP be used to transfer data? BTW I updated my question with an approach I was thinking at the first place.

Comment: @Larme Sorry, I didn't get your comment: it's not possible to send long files, but few developers do that after all?

Comment: @nexuzzz I don't think you can stream A2DP from the device to the phone, you can only go from the phone to the device, and even then, you don't really have much control over it. SDP is a standard bluetooth protocol that lets you use socket communication to transfer data, so you open a socket and send the data through. Now, iOS does not give you direct access to SDP, I think you use iAP instead, its been a while since I have done this. On Android you can just open an SDP connection using RFCOMM. Let me know if you need more detail!

Comment: @Zomb Thanks for the clarification! What do you think about HID+HFP (see original question update)?

Comment: @nexuzzz That will let you transmit audio to and from your device, but it does have other ramifications. Your phone will recognize it as a Hands free device which means that it route phone calls to the device etc. Plus, the bit rate was pretty low if I remember correctly.